# Naming conventions for manual mocks in Jest test runner

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is my project folder structure,

**Folder Structure**

```
app
  - api
    - api1
      __mocks__
          index.js
      - index.js
    - api2
      __mocks__
          index.js
      - index.js
  - components
    -component1
       - index.js
       __tests__
           component1.test.js
```

Right now I have `component1` which internally uses `api1` to do some requests.
There are two issues that I am facing with the current folder structure and mocking the api modules.

1. How should I be naming the files under `api/__mocks__`? should it be `index.js` (the same of as `index.js` under `api1`) or should it be `api1.mocks.js`? Is there a naming convention that is required for jest?
2. Right now with the current structure jest is throwing me the following error,

**Jest Error:**

> jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found:   Module name: index

Is there a documentation somewhere that talks about naming mocks?

This is my jest configuration from package.json,

**package.json:**

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testPathDirs": [
      "<app-path>"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<app-path>"
    ],
    "enableAutomock": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^components": "<rootDir>/components",
      "^services": "<rootDir>/services",
      "^api": "<rootDir>/api",
      "^.+\\.less$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMocks.js"
    }
  }
```

**Simple unit test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Component from 'components/Component1';

jest.mock('api/api1');

describe('Component1 Unit tests', () => {
  it('Should render', () => {
    const c1 = mount(
      <Component1 />
     );
     expect(...);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### ‘Is there a documentation somewhere that talks about naming mocks?’

Yes, the documentation specifies that in [Manual mocks](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html) section:

> Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a `__mocks__/` subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. For example, to mock a module called `user` in the `models` directory, create a file called `user.js` and put it in the `models/__mocks__` directory.

That is **the name of the mock should be the same as of the module**.

---

### ‘Duplicate manual mock found’

When using `moduleNameMapper` the [docs read](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string):

> Modules that are mapped to an alias are unmocked by default.

I am not sure is Jest does not look for the mock either way.

Also please not that `moduleNameMapper` does not work as you seem to assume it does. It does not replace the path parts, it resolves every `require` starting with e.g. `api` to `<rootDir>/api`! (This the does not have any root file.). You should use [ModulePaths](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulepaths-array-string) instad.

The latest *Jest v17* [should give you more info](https://github.com/facebook/jest/commit/a9ba4aac77d3e7cef6da168fadd265b8ddc45849#diff-16f69297ff5bdc25a7a58f3ee8139521R333) about the duplicate.

---

**Note**: The config option `enableAutomock` [does not exist](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#configuration), did you mean `automock`? (Or it should not be there at all?)

**Note**: Similar to naming convention for mocks, inside `__tests__` folder test files usually keep the name of the module, too. The other approach is to add `.spec` or `.test` suffix and keep the test file in the same folder. In both cases it is the easy to find the corresponding test file. Therefore `__tests__/index.js` or `index.test.js` would be good names.

Comment: One note RE the "Modules that are mapped to an alias are unmocked by default". I actually ran into this and couldn't mock them at all (even after calling `jest.mock('aliased/path/here')`. As soon as I removed the alias and instead added the directory to the module paths, everything worked as expected.